# Is it possible to have an inline if with more than one expression per condition?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to have multiple expression in an inline if or do I necessarily need to use the traditional if statement this purpose?

`widget.queueList[j] == 0 ? (jumpAround(); j++;) : widget.queueList[j]--;`

The above is my code, is there a way for me to call `jumpAround()` and increment `j` in the same expression?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
void main() {
  int c = 0;

  c == 0 ? {print('c: $c'), c++, print('c: $c')} : {print('c: $c')};
}
```

Comment: This is a gross hack that abuses `Set` objects.  Please don't do this unless you are intentionally trying to write code that is hard to read.

Comment: @jamesdlin How would you do it differently?

Comment: @ArielH. Just write a normal `if` statement instead of trying to collapse everything into a single expression.  It'd be much more readable.

Comment: Other reasons not to do this: 1. It's not immediately obvious whether the Dart language specification requires that initializers in a `Set` literal be evaluated in left-to-right order. (I *think* it is, but the language specification is written in a very formal way that makes my head hurt.) 2. Adding objects to a `Set` involves calling `.hashCode` on each element, but that makes no sense for a `Set<void>` (which are what the `{` ... `}` create here).  Although it seems to "work" now, I would not be confident that it would continue working in the future.